# When to use datasnapshot.getChildren()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble understanding which is the correct way of retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database.

Supposing I have a node called `users` and that the values are added by a specific ID, when should I iterate the data snapshot and when it is OK to just get the value from `dataSnapshot`.

**More exactly I want to understand when to use this way :**

```
users_node.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                           UserClass user = data.getValue(UserClass.class);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

**and when to use this:**

```
users_node.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        UserClass user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserClass.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

Thank you in advance for taking time to read this!

Answer (score 2):

There is no "right way" for all situations.  Use the method that matches the data you're getting from the query.  If your query returns a snapshot that contains a single UserClass object, then there's no need to loop.  If your query returns a snapshot that contains a list of UserClass objects, then you do need to loop.

Without seeing the data, we don't know which one is right for your particular case.  You will simply have to choose the implementation that matches your data.

Comment: There is no particular data I want to use, I was just asking to learn more about this.  So, you are saying that in a case where I search data after one column, like `users_node.orderByChild("name").equalsTo(x)....` and if it s possible to have many items matching this condition, I should loop?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to in order to process each item individually.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the following database:

```
users
  randomId
     name : john
     age : 40
```

If you want to access both the `name` and `age`, and you don't have access to the `randomId`, then you use `for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){` to iterate and you will retrieve the values of type `String`.

If you have your own POJO class, with `name` field, `age` field, and empty constructor, then you dont have to iterate since if you iterate you will retrieve the values of type String and not of type `User` (POJO class).